# Connecting ASP.NET to MDF file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I finally got [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) to work. I attached the [Adventure Works sample database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124501.aspx) to it.

Now I would like to display data from that database in ASP.NET. I would like to run SQL statements from ASP.NET.

How do I do this?

Comment: Might want to check out this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6759sth4.aspx

Comment: From the [horses mouth](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-videos/)